# Jibx unmarshal run time error: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, xml, jibx

I read XML contant from file and pass xml stream to convert xml to object. I'm not sure why im getting below the error when i running the unmarshal in jibx runtime.
I incuded jibx  /lib/jibx-run.jar and /lib/xpp3.jar jar in to the project classpath.

Note: I have class in   com.bbb.plugins.ccc.objects.Envelope but i don't have JiBX_abcd_binding_newi... methon in that class

still i'm not abale to undastand why jibx runtime looking someother methond

```
 ERROR  Problem while processing the message : 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bbb.plugins.ccc.objects.Envelope.JiBX_abcd_binding_newinstance_1_0(Lcom/bbb/plugins/ccc/objects/Envelope;Lorg/jibx/runtime/impl/UnmarshallingContext;)Lcom/bbb/plugins/ccc/objects/Envelope;
    at com.bbb.plugins.ccc.objects.JiBX_abcd_bindingEnvelope_access.unmarshal() ~[ccc-poller-schema-0.0.14.jar:na]
    at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:2757) ~[jibx-run-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at com.company.ccc.util.XMLParser.makeObject(XMLParser.java:65) ~[main/:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all duplication class load from the class path.

axis.8716.n7.nabble.com/NoSuchMethodError-when-service-classes-and-JiBX-data-binding-classes-are-located-in-WEB-INF-classes-td35316.html